# Getting store not found error in React Native Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

My `App.js` file is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import reducers from './reducers';

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <View>
          <Text>12345</Text>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".
```

I can't figure out where the error is. How do I solve this?

Comment: why you are exporting app with  connect(mapStateToProps)(App); 
its not required . remove this and i think it can we works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach almost correct, but still need tweak. The problem is because `connect` try to find the redux store instance, but do not have reference about it.

You need to move the `connect` and wrap the children component instead the root.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import reducers from './reducers';

const Content = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>12345</Text>
  </View>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
};

// Use connect enhancer, when the parent is wrapped with <Provider>
const EnhancedContent = connect(mapStateToProps)(Content);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <EnhancedContent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```